# How to pass Pillow image data to scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, python-imaging-library

I am trying to train an image classifier in scikit-learn. I have a bunch of input images and I am using Pillow to process them. My question is about what shape to give the Pillow data to scikit-learn.

This is my code now:

```
training = glob.glob('./img/training/*/*.bmp')
data = []
classes = []
for imagefile in training:
    edges = Image.open(imagefile).filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES).convert("L")
    in_data = np.asarray(edges, dtype=np.uint8)
    data.append(in_data[0])
    if 'class1' in imagefile:
        classes.append('class1')
    else:
        classes.append('class2')
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)
clf.fit(data, classes)
```

This runs without errors, but I have put the code together fairly crudely and I am not sure it is correct.

In particular, I'm not sure whether I should be using `in_data[0]`. I just did this because using `in_data` gives me an error: `ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want the first row of the image matrix ( in_data[0] returns you the first row ) of each image, you probably want to use flattening.

Flattening will take each row of the image matrix and put the rows behind eachother in a 1 dimensional vector.

So it becomes data.append(in_data.flatten())

You could resize your image to a smaller format first, to reduce the number of columns of your data matrix.